# Some program is slow to close during shutdown

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Win 7 Home Premium 64 bit.  I close everything I started, shutdown and the "Waiting for Program to Close" message comes up.  Is there a log file I can examine to determine what program is causing this?

Comment: You might find something in the event log.

Comment: Weird. . .  I tried to clear my event log, so I could see what may be causing the issue; Event Viewer takes 30-45 seconds to load and HDD activity is VERY high.  Then, it shows events from 2011.  It seems to be loading this from backup logs I can't kill.

Comment: That sounds like a HDD problem. I would clone the drive personally.

Comment: This happens to me all the time. Usually the culprit is a service that's slow to close.

Comment: USB drive shutting down?